# How to post with a link onclick as well as submit a name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So on a page, I have a link. it is part of a button dropdown list.

```
<li id="acli1"><a id="aclnk1" href="" onClick="document.forms['frm'].submit()" name="acceptfriend">Accept Friend Request</a></li>
```

at the top of the page i have:

```
if(isset($_POST['acceptfriend']))
{
    echo "<script>alert('boo')</script>";
}
```

When I click this link, I want to reach the alert.
But for some reason, after submitting the form and refreshing the page, it does not reach. My guess is it submits the form considering the page refreshes. But for some reason, it does not carry over the name attribute i set for it.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

The form itself

```
<form id="frm" action="<?php echo "./".$uname; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console. You'll what you're doing wrong.

Comment: 1. What happens if you inspect the POST object in console after click? 2. Can you confirm that the form name matches "frm" ?

Comment: do you want a ajax call or refresh the same page?

Comment: I dont know how. Is it possible to view post objects debugging in chrome?

Comment: Also fred, that shows me how to submit yes, but how do i pass through a name?

Comment: ask the guy who gave you an answer below with the same Stack page link as the possible duplicate I posted @happinin

Comment: Show your `<form>` specifically the `method="??"` I would guess it says `method="GET"` or not entered at all

Comment: never mind, the guy deleted the answer now. Post your full code

Comment: The form worked with every other submit button

  `<form id="frm" action="<?php echo "./".$uname; ?>" method="post">`

Comment: don't post code in comments, post it all in an edit instead http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38855006/edit you also didn't check for errors as previously stated.

Comment: I also previously stated I dont know how to debug POST. 
Will put in edit now.

Comment: Ahh this anchor named `acceptfriend` is not an `<input>` field and therefore does not get sent to the PHP script ever. Only `<input>` `<select>` `<textarea>` _have I forgotten anything_ get sent to the PHP script

Comment: Ahhh @RiggsFolly ! How do I work around that? The reason that I had it as an <a> tag is because I was using a bootstrap button dropdown.
That takes a list of links instead of inputs. If there was a possible bootstrap style dropdown button list in a list of inputs would be nice.

Comment: Depends upon what you are doing in this form, and as we have little idea about that, ___I dunno___

Comment: @RiggsFolly , your answer still helped!

I just changed the link to an input of type submit, gave it the same css settings plus a few extras such as no border and it worked!

Your answer was correct. nice catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your code snippet below -

```
<a id="aclnk1" href="" onClick="document.forms['frm'].submit()" name="acceptfriend">Accept Friend Request</a>
```

1. **href = "#"** is missing which means your form is not submitting.
2. In your code, the value of action is not self link of the page-

   ```
   <form id="frm" action="<?php echo "./".$uname; ?>" method="post">
   ```

   So, to make the page submit to itself,
   make **action =  "`<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`"** or **action = "#"**
3. **if(isset($_POST['acceptfriend']))** condition won't be true for an **anchor tag(`<a>`)**.

   Try using a button with a **name attribute** for e.g.-

   `<button name="submitbutton">Submit Form</button>`

   so if the button is clicked, The condition **if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']))** will become true.

Comment: The action itself was correct because i used a .htaccess file to customise user profile pages. The problem lay within the link itself. I had to use a button with a name in order to communicate. so what i did was replace with a button and style it as a link.